# How to systematically troubleshoot a broken gnu-screen installation?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, terminfo, iterm2, termcap

I recently started to work in a shared Linux cluster that a version of gnu-screen that I consider unacceptably old (4.01, from 2006).

I was not able to convince the system's administrators to install a more recent version of gnu-screen, so I installed my own off my home directory, using `conda`.

Unfortunately, even after I installed my long-trusted `~/.screenrc` file, my `conda`-installed instance of gnu-screen does not work well at all.

For example, the backspace key does not erase the character to the left of the cursor; instead, it behaves like the space key, at least as far as what shows up on the screen.  Hitting the `C-r` key, which I use *all the time* to search my history, disfigures my screen grotesquely.  Other than gnu-screen's "command key" (which I have set to `C-h`), pretty much any chord involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is messed up.  Etc.

I should emphasize that all these problems emerge only after I start a new `gnu-screen` session, using my `conda`-installed instance of `gnu-screen`.  Outside of screen, or when I use the ancient `/usr/bin/screen`, my terminal behaves normally.

Still, I suspect that the problem may have something to do with my `TERM` variable's setting at the time of invoking `screen` (namely `TERM=xterm-256color`), and/or the terminal emulator I am using (iTerm2 running on OS X), but I don't know how to go beyond these hunches.

When I search online for solutions to this problem I come across massive amounts of trial-and-error.

Is there a systematic, reasonable way to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: If there is a systematic, reasonable way, I don't know it so I'm looking forward to the answers you might get! That said, it is probably worth checking out your `~/.inputrc` if you have one.

Comment: @terdon: As it happens, I don't have an `~/.inputrc` file at all.  In fact, if ever in my life I had one, I never noticed it!  Now I wonder if my not having an `~/.inputrc` file could be the problem...  Time for me to find more about `~/.inputrc`.  Thank you for the pointer!

Comment: No, if you don't have one that won't be a problem. It's just the default file where you can set user-specific settings for the `readline` library. I tend to play with it and this results in unexpected issues on new systems where my inputrc isn't set up as I want it. But that's also where you set things like allowing Ctrl+arrows to act like Alt+B and Alt+F (jump to the next/previous word) so you might be able to set some things there to help you out. Please note that I have a very limited understanding of the details of this though, this is just a shot in the dark.